# Azure DevOps error 401 when joining new organization

Tags: azure, azure-devops, outlook

I want to join a project but when i click on '*Join now*' button inside invitation email, get 401 error.

> 401 - Uh-oh, you do not have access.
> Your account, **** is not authorized to view this page. Make sure the URL is correct and your account has access. View a list of your organizations here. You may request access by contacting the admin.
> 6/25/2021 3:14:19 PM (UTC)
> a48b3930-10f2-4b1d-90f4-7a034be47a70

I also cleared cookies & cache, close all browsers, use incognito tab but no chance...

Comment: This might not solve your issue but just in case.:
Could you ask the Azure DevOps admin of that organization to resend you the invitation?
Have you already tried that?

Comment: Also ask if they have given you access to the desired project

Comment: as per said, you need to contact the admin (project admin or project collection admin) of the organisation/project you would like to join. there may in private project/permission set disallowed public accessible.

Comment: @SebastianInones yes I tried resend invitation. also remove and add multiple times, change access level, set user as administrator, ... does not work. very weird issue. I also ask my question in developer community  https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Error-401-when-joining-an-organization-v/1461243?space=21&q=migrate+tenant&entry=myfeedback

Comment: Was there any solution?